# Can't combine button-disable and code-behind function (JavaScript + code-behind)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

When clicking on `Insert`-button, it does whatever it's suppose to do. But I don't want user to be able to click the button more than once and therefore I want to disable it once you press it.

```
<asp:Button ID="Insert" runat="server" Text="Send" OnClick="Insert_OnClick" 
  OnClientClick="this.disabled=true; showLoading(this);" />
```

When combining `Insert_OnClick` and "`disable`", the function `Insert_OnClick` wont run, because it somehow disable the button first and therefore the code-behind function wont run for that reason.

I also tried to disable to button itself in `showLoading` js-function, same behavior.

Any idea how to make the code-behind function run as the button get disabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to disable it in code behind. Even if you did disable it after the click, the changes made with javascript would still be undone after PostBack.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Insert.Enabled = false;
}
```

Or set a timeout on the OnClientClick? Maybe that will work.

```
OnClientClick="setTimeout(function () { this.disabled=true; }, 10);"
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the user will get redirected to another page when pressing that button, therefore `btnInsert.Enabled = false;` is not necessary. However, I need to disable the button after one press so they can't run the code-behind function twice by double-clicking it before they get redirected.

Comment: Still, double clicking should not be an issue. But if you really want to prevent it you can set a Session in code behind, check for that in the second click and remove it on Page2.

Comment: Double clicking is an issue. I may be wrong but it session-solution sounds like overdoing it. I guess there is a simpler solution with JavaScript, to enable to run the code as the button gets disabled.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Won't work for some odd reason.. The timeout works, but it still register double click. I also tried with time  `1` as it should be faster than double click. This is so confusing.

Comment: Well moving that timeout code into `showLoading(this)` made it work for some reason. I don't know why it didn't work via `OnClientClick`. 

The only change I did was: `setTimeout(function () { document.getElementById("Insert").disabled = true; }, 10);`

Thanks.

Comment: this doesn't work until the postback is done, if the button needs to be disabled, then it should be disabled right away after click, 
The set timeout will disable the button shorty after the click... even a fast missing double click can launch the process again. best uption is to submit the whole form instead of using the whole button

Answer (score 0):

If possible, I would change the Submit behavior.

the problem with that approach is that the front end code takes place before the back end submit and if you disable the button before the back end submit then it won't be able to call the back end function.

Instead i would use different approaches, like consuming a webMethod or submiting the whole form .

with the web method you would be able to play a little bit with the front end while the back end finishes processing

With the whole submit you'll have to play with the page_load Event